# How to create a "30 second countdown timer"?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

How do I write a simple countdown timer in either 
android? For android, assume there is a textedit field called timerdisplay that will display a countdown from 30 seconds to 0

Comment: http://dewful.com/?p=3  here's exactly what you are looking for. Please use search next time before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
You can use java timer Api to make a timer control using
**java.util.Timer**
**Class Timer**